# How do I find how many different elements does a list have? in lisp

Tags: list, lisp

How do I find, in Lisp, how many different elements does a list have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(length (remove-duplicates <your list>))
```

The shortest way of doing it, but it is also possible to do it in a single pass, like so:

```
(defun count-distinct (list)
  (let ((table (make-hash-table)))
    (dolist (i list (hash-table-count table))
      (setf (gethash i table) t))))
```

Comment: the `remove-duplicates` function doesn't work if the list given is as follows: `((1 2 3) (1 2 3) (4 5 6))`for example. Just tested it with clisp... Neither does the `count-distinct`functions
Do you know any other way?

Comment: The elements in the list are all of type `(int int 'tXXX)` (the XXX is a number between 000 and 999). example: `(1 22 't121)` as lisp would print it: `(1 22 T121)`

Comment: you should change your name do lispGenius or I should change mine to lispIgnorant